# How to fix 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str''

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord.py economy bot, so I first started with the currency. I am working with somebody make a system where you can add coins to somebody and see how many coins you have, but I am getting these errors.

This is for a discord.py economy bot. I'm new to rewrite, so I probably made a silly mistake, but I can't find it.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
token = 

def user_add_coins(user_id: int, points: int):
    if os.path.isfile("coins.json"):
        try:
            with open('coins.json', 'r') as fp:
                users = json.load(fp)
            users[user_id]['coins'] += points
            with open('coins.json', 'w') as fp:
                json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        except KeyError:
            with open('coins.json', 'r') as fp:
                users = json.load(fp)
            users[user_id] = {}
            users[user_id]['coins'] = points
            with open('coins.json', 'w') as fp:
                json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    else:
        users = {"user_id": {}}
        users[user_id]['coins'] = points
        with open('coins.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def get_points(user_id: int):
    if os.path.isfile('coins.json'):
        with open('coins.json', 'r') as fp:
            users = json.load(fp)
        return users[user_id]['coins']
    else:
        return 0

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    user_add_coins(message.author.id, 1)

@bot.command()
async def coins(ctx):
    coins = get_points(ctx.author.id)
    await ctx.send(f"Your Coins Is `{coins}` !")

@bot.group()
async def add(ctx):
    if ctx.command_invk is None:
        return

@add.command()
async def coins(ctx, args: int, member: discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.id in owners:
        user_add_coins(member.id, int(args))
        await ctx.send(f"Sussces Add {args} to {member.mention} !")


bot.run(token)
```

This is the error message, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MYNAME/PycharmProjects/Faction Discord Bot/Faction Discord Test Bot.py", line 14, in user_add_coins
    users[user_id]['coins'] += points
KeyError: 474744664449089556

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 255, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/MYNAME/PycharmProjects/Faction Discord Bot/Faction Discord Test Bot.py", line 40, in on_message
    user_add_coins(message.author.id, 1)
  File "C:/Users/MYNAME/PycharmProjects/Faction Discord Bot/Faction Discord Test Bot.py", line 23, in user_add_coins
    json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\json\encoder.py", line 430, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Users\MYNAME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\json\encoder.py", line 353, in _iterencode_dict
    items = sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0])
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Sorry for the code spam.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the users in `users` have numeric keys and some others have string keys. By passing `sort_keys=True` to `dump()` you insist that the users are sorted by their keys, which in this case is not possible: you cannot mix apples and oranges. Solution: remove that option.

```
json.dump(users, fp, indent=4)
```

Comment: Better yet, fix `users` so that all the keys *are* numeric; that seems to be the expected type based on `def user_add_coins(user_id: int, points: int):`.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer as the reason for the error was given as well as a solution that solves incompatible mixed key types and the ```sort_keys=True``` argument for ```json.dump```.  It helped me.